# Flask sqlalchemy import error, different error

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an import error while coding a flask web application. Here are my imports:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import session, request
from flask import render_template, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy
```

Although the last line of code gives me the error:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy
```

I have successfully installed Flask, SQLAlchemy, and Flask-SQLAlchemy using pip, and I have checked whether these are installed on the system using

```
python -c "import Flask"
```

etc. These checks resulted in a 0, meaning that it was correctly installed. NOTE: I have already read other posts, and tried flask.ext.sqlalchemy, flaskext_sqlalchemy, etc. as import variations. Here are the installed packages in the sitepackages directory for python 2.7.

```
Flask_OAuth-0.12.dist-info      httplib2
Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2.dist-info    httplib2-0.10.3.dist-info
SQLAlchemy-1.2.0.dist-info      oauth2
flask_oauth.py              oauth2-1.9.0.post1.dist-info
flask_oauth.pyc             sqlalchemy
flask_sqlalchemy            tests
```

I have also structured my files, so the imports are in the **init**.py file. My other files included views.py, config.py, run.py, and a templates folder containing html files.
What am I doing wrong here, and how is my problem different from others?

Comment: It may be case sensitive.  `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` works on one of my projects

Comment: That is not the error, as it has a problem importing flask_sqlalchemy, not SQLAlchemy itself.

Comment: That list of installed packages doesn't include Flask... but its not complaining about that?

Comment: Flask was installed in a separate directory, but when I installed Flask-SQLAlchemy or SQLAlchemy it stated that the requirement for Flask was satisfied.

Comment: have you tried putting all of your code in a virtualenv and reinstalling all the packages there?

Answer (score 0):

Module imports are indeed case sensitive.

The way to check this is to first confirm if it's possible to:

```
import flask_sqlalchemy
```

If that succeeds, the package is installed correctly. Once the package is confirmed to be installed correctly, then this should succeed.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: Got downvoted, but without any additional context. Comment above says "That's not the issue", but it very clearly looks like the issue. Please provide more details that show why case does not matter, and if my two steps above indeed work :)